# Should I explicitly return list from function?

Tags: python

I want to do some list modification in a function and then continue to use the modified list after calling the function, which is the better approach to do this:

```
def modify(alist):
    alist.append(4)
alist = [1,2,3]
modify(alist)
alist.append(5)
```

Or this:

```
def modify(alist):
    alist.append(4)
    return alist
alist = [1,2,3]
alist = modify(alist)
alist.append(5)
```

Is the first some kind of bad tone?

Comment: Depends on your criteria for "better" and how one determines the "tone" of code.

Comment: No, the first is fine - Python functions that alter the state of mutable arguments generally `return None` (either explicitly or implicitly) - *just like `.append` itself!*

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027694/correct-style-for-python-functions-that-mutate-the-argument

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily a function should *return* the results it generates. However when you pass a list, you either need to make a *copy* of the list or accept the fact that it will be modified; it's redundant to return the modified list. It also leads to a problem if you ever provide a default argument, since the default will also be modified.

I generally prefer to make arguments read-only unless it's obvious that they will be modified inplace.

My recommendation:

```
def modify(alist=[]):
    alist = alist[:] # make a copy
    alist.append(4)
    return alist
```

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to return the list from a function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jack!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're modifying the list *inplace*, it would not make much sense to return the same list you have modified.

Your *inplace* mutation *propagates* from the reference to the `list`, so better to leave out the `return` statement and raise an exception if an error occurs somewhere in the function, but not `return` the modified object.

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: You shouldn't *"return a value that indicates the status of the mutation"* - if the operation fails, raise an exception.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Brainfart on that. Wasn't paying attention. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Formally, both approaches fullfil the task you want - to modify a list.

But, the second approach with function `return` some value which is stored in your variable is safer, and such code is much-much easier to maintain and develop, especially if you have many lists to modify, for example. Or in general you have a code that solves some difficult task, for which you need a lot of functions and variables. "Safe" means you don't have to worry about variable name conflict inside you code - everything you create inside your function namespace, stays local (except the case when you create a class attribute). So, it's generally considered a better practice. Good luck!

Comment: Down voter, want to explain? Is there something wrong with my reasoning? Plaese correct then.