# Python my function keeps returning an empty list

Tags: python, list

```
 lists = [['12','saw'],['12','dan'],['16','man']]

 contain = []

 def foo(y, x):
     host = [item[0].lower() for item in y]
     unique_labels = []
     for item, count in collections.Counter(host).items():
        if count == 1:
            unique_labels.append(item)
            x = [item for item in y if item[0] in unique_labels]
     return x

 foo(lists,contain) 
 print contain #returns an empty list instead of a list of lists
```

Hi, I have this function that takes a list of lists and returns a new list of lists based on a certain condition. However, when I call the function and try to view the new list of lists, it returns the empty list. I don't understand why 'contain' is empty. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Because you don't actually mutate the list you pass in; sometimes you replace it with a new one, and you return it, but you don't do anything with what's returned. Either return *or* mutate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for replying but I am still a beginner and I am not sure how to go about 'returning or mutating'. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Then I'd recommend some research, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/26027694/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, I've got it now

Answer (score 0):

List `contain` starts empty and you never modify it, so it is empty when you print it.  The function `foo` receives `contain` as an argument for parameter `x`.  Foo does not add anything to the argument.  Instead, it *repeatedly* rebinds the *name* `x` to a new list, and then returns the last new list.  Your code ignores the returned list, and it is deleted.

If `foo` is supposed to fill in the input argument `x`, it should have `x.append` or `x.extend` calls and *never* rebind with `x = ...`.