# **kwargs: Why is the below list comprehension not printing outputs while normal for loop does?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3 I am trying to print the outputs of a `**kwargs` using a list comprehension. I am unable to do so while using a `for` loop does print the elements of my list input. Below is the reproducible code:

Using list comprehension:

```
class Practice(object):
    __acceptable_keys_list = ['Right', 'left']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        temp = ([self.__setattr__(key, kwargs.get(key)) for key in self.__acceptable_keys_list])
        print(temp)
```

Output is `[None, None]`.

Where as using a `for` loop:

```
class Practice(object):
    __acceptable_keys_list = ['Right', 'Left']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):   
         for key in self.__acceptable_keys_list:
             self.__setattr__(key,kwargs.get(key))
             print(key)
```

Output is `[Right, Left]`.

Why the difference ? What am I missing ? Shouldn't list comp and for loops behave in similar manner?

**Edit:** Why the downvotes ? I am trying to understand things here.

Comment: `__setattr__` returns `None`.

Comment: Those two aren't equivalent, try using `temp=self.__setattr__(key,kwargs.get(key));print(temp)` in the second one

Comment: Abusing a list comprehension for its side effect is a big no no: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027694/correct-style-for-python-functions-that-mutate-the-argument) explain why its conventional in Python for mutating methods to return `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Coding Style

You are abusing a side-effect in a list comprehension. This is [considered very bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/).

#### Return Value of __setattr__

Nonetheless, as already mentioned by @Aran-Fey, [__setattr__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) returns `None`. Your Code is not equivalent. The following code does the same:

```
class Practice(object):
    __acceptable_keys_list = ['Right', 'Left']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Please do **NOT** do this at home!
        temp = ([self.__setattr__(key, kwargs.get(key)) for key in self.__acceptable_keys_list])
        print(temp)

class Practice(object):
    __acceptable_keys_list = ['Right', 'Left']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         temp = []
         for key in self.__acceptable_keys_list:
             # Use the return value of __setattr__, which is None
             temp.append(self.__setattr__(key,kwargs.get(key)))
         print(temp)
```

Comment: The second one in your answer makes sense. Looping and appending elements to an empty list. Thank you.

Comment: And what is the "first one"? Do you mean the comment about side effects in list comprehensions? This is **really** a bad idea.

Comment: @WaterRocket8236 If this is the answer to your question, please mark it accordingly :)

Comment: I meant the list comp as the "first one". Yes i understand thats a bad idea. Just trying stuffs out. Was unaware of __setattr__ return value.