# Called itself (function) inside for loop, and it changes local variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def findPair(students, Robert):
    #...
        if len(students) == 2:
            #do something
            return
        else:
            for friend in friendsOfRobert:
                print(students)
                leftStudents = removePairFromStudents(students, friend, Robert)
                if len(leftStudents) != 0:
                    findPair(leftStudents, leftStudents[0])
            return
```

I don't quite understand why `students` is modified as it loops inside `for`. It is not even global variable. The following is just to help you see the structure of the code.

1. ... part : find `friendsOfRobert` from `students`
2. for loop

   (1) suppose one `friend` and `Robert` was paired.

   (2) `leftStudent`: Remove the `friend` and `Robert` from `students`

   (3) Repeat `findPair` but this time without the `friend` and `Robert`. The next equivalent of `Robert` is randomly selected (`leftStudents[0]`)

On the side note, I solved the issue by remembering the pair previously removed, and rebuilding the original `students` set each time (with code below) before it dives into the next loop.

```
if len(students) == 2:
    if len(justPaired) != 0:
        students.append(justPaired[0])
        students.append(justPaired[1])
    # do something
    return
```

edit : removed unnecessary example

Comment: You seem to be under the misunderstanding that functions get a copy of their arguments. This is not the case, they get the original object and can modify it (if it is mutable).

Comment: The local variable ``students`` is not changed. The object referred to by ``students`` is changed. Use a ``tuple`` instead of a ``list`` if you want an immutable sequence.

Comment: @L3viathan Ohhh.. this makes it clear. Thank you for mentioning the mutable part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct Style for Python functions that mutate the argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027694/correct-style-for-python-functions-that-mutate-the-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions *do not* get a copy of their argument. They get a *copy of the reference* to the argument. So, when you write

```
 f(x):
     x.append(3)
     x = [2,4,5]


 y = [1, 2]
 f(y)
```

the line `x.append(3)` affects the *actual list* that was passed, while the line `x = [2, 4, 6]` has no effect because it re-assigns the copy of the reference to the argument.